# UITableViewCell stretchable backgroundView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with variable height cells. I would prefer not to have to use a background image, but rather would like to set a `backgroundView` with the styling that I want. Currently, I can't figure out how to dynamically change the height of my `backgroundView` based on the height of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 60)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
        view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 0.4;
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
        [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:view];

    }

    ZSSLog *log = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = log.logText;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Right now the background views just overlap since they are not being resized:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the frame of your background view you might want to do something like

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

This answer assumes you're not using auto-layout since you're setting the frame of your background view. If you're using auto-layout you don't want to be setting the frame at all and instead setting constraints on your background view.

Comment: No, not using auto-layout or any part of IB. This worked! Just needed the autoresizing code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd use the `backgroundView` property for this. Try setting up your background view like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
view.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(view.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10));
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
//...other cell config...
cell.backgroundView = view;
```

But if you really want to put this view inside the `contentView`, you can do that like:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
view.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(view.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10));
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
//...other cell config...
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];
```